# Traduzir site que já está desenvolvido

Tags: php

Tenho um site de um cliente que já esta desenvolvido e rodando normalmente, porém agora o cliente quer o site em inglês e espanhol, ai vem a dúvida, grosseiramente, eu poderia duplicar os arquivos e traduzir o site todo, porem isso é muito arcaico.

Eis a duvida, existe alguma forma fácil de traduzir este site? O backend está em PHP e sem framework.

Obs.: Já tenho todos os conteúdos em inglês e espanhol

Comment: é amplo demais.. sem ver o sistema é inviável opinar qualquer coisa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar um arquivo que contenha um `array()` contendo o conteúdo nos idiomas respectivos.

### Exemplo

```
$varArray = [

   'pt'     => [
       'titulo' => 'Produtos',
   ];

   'en'     => [
       'titulo' => 'Products',
   ];

   'en'     => [
       'titulo' => 'Produtos',
   ];

]
```

Na página você terá que ter o idioma em **sessão** e o `include` do arquivo.

```
include "traducao.php";
$idioma = $_SESSION['idioma']; # pt, en ou es
```

Daí no lugar que você irá traduzir:

```
<h2>
    <?php 
        echo $varArray[$idioma]['titulo'];
    ?>
</h2>
```

Comment: Poxa mto obrigado !!! Vou tentar aqui =D

Answer (score 5):

### Você pode fazer isso de duas maneiras

**A trabalhosa:** Crie uma folha com todas as variáveis possíveis em uma biblioteca e traduza o conteúdo usando um arquivo do tipo .ini e usar `parse_ini_file()`: **http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-ini-file.php**

Um exemplo de uso:
**translate.ini**

```
;arquivo de traduções
[pt-br]
;tradução português
title = 'Olá Mundo'
text = 'Seu texto entra aqui'
data_formato = 'd/m/Y'
[en]
;english translate
title = 'Hello World'
text = 'Your text enter here'
data_formato = 'm/d/Y'
[es]
;traducion español
title = 'Hola Mundo';
text = 'Su texto va aquí'
data_formato = 'd/m/Y'
```

No PHP:

```
<?php
    $translate = parse_ini_file('translate.ini', true);

    $lang = 'pt-br';

    $titulo = $translate[$lang]['title'];
    $texto = $translate[$lang]['text'];
?>
```

**A rápida:** use a API do Google:
https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs
https://translate.google.com/manager/website/
RESTful: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest

Comment: Po vlww vou dar uma olhada aqui =D